# Joining two models with 2 different controllers

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, entity-framework-4

I've model1=Position, model2=User, model3 = indexListings

model1 :int ID, int Name_pos
model2 : current_position= model1.ID

I want to display the values in View of model3, indexListings. The user's posiion ID shouldn't show, but the corresponding string Name_pos should show.

However, only the seeded initial values show (which i created in the configuration file). Newly created entries dont show.

So for joining two models, i used

```
       public ActionResult Index(int? page)
    {
       UserDBContext db = new UserDBContext();

            //   var v = (from m in db.Users join r in db.DBPositions on m.current_position equals r.ID select new IndexListing() { position_name = r.Name_pos }).ToList();
            IEnumerable<IndexListing> v = from m in db.Users.AsEnumerable()
                                          join r in db.DBPositions.AsEnumerable()


                                          select new IndexListing { position_name = r.Name_pos, user_name = m.UserName_ID, };//).ToList();
            //GET ALL DETAILS OF LISTING INDEX

   int pageSize = 10;
            int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
            return View(v.OrderBy(i => i.user_name).ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
}
```

I used database update for seeding a few values in table (modle) User and (model) Position.
However on adding new User instance, the listing index doesn't include the newly added user. Only the seeded data shows from Configuration file.
IS my DB context flawed?

```
public class UserDBContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Position> DBPositions { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I honestly don't know what you're asking. Where is the second controller? What is the output you're getting versus the output you're expecting? How are you updating the database? How are you getting the "DETAILS OF LISTING INDEX"?

Comment: Edited my question. Hope its more clear to understand.